# MsgBox+InputBox with Numbers,verify input number with If

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie alert. I'm using a `MsgBox` and an `InputBox` combination which asks a user whether they want to delete a row (msgbox) with a specified value (inputbox). I am looping it until I get a `vbNo` in the `Msgbox`, which seems to work, however the InputBox user value validation does not seem to work. 

I've read that Inputboxes recognise values as String, so not sure if this could be an issue?

My queries

1) I want to limit users to enter Numbers only into the input box, which are also no longer than 4 digits. I'm using the If statements for this, but none work. I was thinking of assigning an Inputbox Type to Integer, and it limits input to numbers, but there is no warning if user mistypes and not all will know what they're doing wrong.

2) When I put the line `If UserValue = vbNullString Then GoTo Continue` which is the opposite to `If UserValue <> vbNullString Then GoTo StoreEntered` - the procedure doesn't work, is there a difference? Any suggestions much appreciated.

3) **UPD** I've just tried clicking `vbYes on Mgsbox` and then `Cancel on InputBox` and I swear it worked before, but doesn't seem to work anymore. I would have thought that referencing to the `vbNullString` would solve the issue of not entering anything and clicking OK or simply Cancelling the inputBox.

Here is my code

```
Dim UserValue As Integer
Dim UserReply As Variant

KeepLoop:
Do
UserReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you want any store transactions removed?", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Stores removed")
    If UserReply = vbNo Then GoTo Continue
    If UserReply = vbYes Then GoTo UserInputReqd
Loop Until UserReply = vbNo

UserInputReqd:
UserValue = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter any store number you want removed from the file. Otherwise click Cancel", _
                Title:="CHOSE STORES TO RUN OR DELETE") ', Type:=1)

        If UserValue <> vbNullString Then GoTo StoreEntered 'If user left line blank and clicked 'Ok' or clicked 'Cancel'
        If Not IsNumeric(UserValue) Then
                MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value"
        If Len(UserValue) > 4 Then
                MsgBox "Max store number is 4 digits", vbCritical
        End If
        End If

StoreEntered:
r = 100000
Do
If Sheets(csv_sht).Cells(r, 1) = UserValue Then Sheets(csv_sht).Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
r = r - 1
Loop Until r = 1
GoTo KeepLoop

Continue: 'Next step, continue as normal.
==Code here==

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what the exact message flow should be if you don't enter a store number, but something like this should simplify things:

```
Dim UserValue             As Variant
Dim UserReply             As Variant
Do
    UserReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you want any store transactions removed?", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Stores removed")
    If UserReply = vbYes Then

        UserValue = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter any store number you want removed from the file. Otherwise click Cancel", _
                                         Title:="CHOSE STORES TO RUN OR DELETE")
        If UserValue = vbNullString Then
            ' do nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(UserValue) Then
                MsgBox "You must enter a numeric value"
        ElseIf Len(UserValue) > 4 Then
                MsgBox "Max store number is 4 digits", vbCritical
        Else
            For r = 100000 To 1 Step -1
                If Sheets(csv_sht).Cells(r, 1) = CLng(UserValue) Then Sheets(csv_sht).Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
            Next r
        End If
    End If
Loop Until UserReply = vbNo
'Next step, continue as normal.
```

Comment: If you don't enter a store number or Cancel, or click No on the MsgBox, it just takes you to the label Continue (at the bottom) which just contains the rest of the code that's not related to this Msgbox/InputBox combo. Many thanks! I'll try this asap and let you know

Comment: Thank you Rory, it does what I had in mind, much appreciated!